# Why cant my reader import the basereader from the file?

Tags: python, reader, audio-fingerprinting

i am trying to run a file "reader_microphone.py" with some of its line below

```
  import pyaudio
    import numpy
    import wave
    from reader import basereader

    class MicrophoneReader(BaseReader):
      default_chunksize = 8192
      default_format = pyaudio.paInt16
      default_channels = 2
      default_rate = 44100
      default_seconds = 0
```

---

i am getting this error-

```
from reader import basereader

ImportError: cannot import name 'basereader' from 'reader' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\reader.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and welcome to StackOverflow.

There is no basereader reference in the reader package. You can take a look at the package's documentation [here](https://reader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), to try and see what's the object you are looking for.